# How to make secure ldap connection with encrypted key?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openldap, stringio, python-ldap

I am writing below ldap client side code to connect to secure ldap server.

```
import ldap
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_KEYFILE, 'a/b/key.txt')
```

But my key.txt contains a encrypted key which needs passphrase.

Could you please let me know how do I pass passphrase for the above function.

I am using python-ldap module.

I also tried to use StringIO object by keeping decrypted key in StringIO object, but the set_option method is expecting string value instead of StringIO object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python-ldap module is a wrapper over OpenLDAP package. Unfortunately OpenLDAP cannot operate with password-protected private key. And you cannot provide file descriptor for a key, you should provide a path or path-like object to be used by the c language open() function. You have several ways there:

- Keep the private key decrypted (not the best, but simplest);
- Decrypt private key into a temporary file or into a file-like object, provide to ldap, then delete;
- use Python [ldap3 package](https://pypi.org/project/ldap3/);
- create a LDAP to LDAP-TLS proxy

---

Part of OpenLDAP source where `OPT_X_TLS_KEYFILE` value been used as the `path` parameter:

```
    static int
    tlsg_getfile( const char *path, gnutls_datum_t *buf )
    {
      int rc = -1, fd;
      struct stat st;

      fd = open( path, O_RDONLY );
      if ( fd >= 0 && fstat( fd, &st ) == 0 ) {
        buf->size = st.st_size;
        buf->data = LDAP_MALLOC( st.st_size + 1 );
        if ( buf->data ) {
          rc = read( fd, buf->data, st.st_size );
          close( fd );
          if ( rc < st.st_size )
            rc = -1;
          else
            rc = 0;
        }
      }
      return rc;
    }
```